# Blank screen after installing nvidia-current drivers

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I have MSI GX701 with Nvidia 9600M GT! I was using Ubuntu 10.4 and windows 7 until I decided to install only Ubuntu 11.10. Installation worked like a charm for me! Everything was ok until I installed additional drivers for Nvidia (I choose recommended)!

Then the screen turns blank, computer is not responding to any command, but the processor still works. Now when I reboot manually, after I log in it passes around 40 seconds until screen turns blank again.

I saw that people usually fix problems with this by "rolling back" drivers, but I need to know if this problem is fixed so I can use Ubuntu in 3D! I'm not a total beginner, but I would like help "spelled out" if you can! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago.

You may want to rename /etc/X11/xorg.conf and reboot to let Ubuntu create a new xorg.conf file.